# Bookmarklet To Read Specific Text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bookmarklet

I have a site which is running in 3 web servers and it is accessed via load balanced URL. The site has a code to display web server name something like this `<!-- Machine Name= WEBSERVER1 -->` (in case the site is accessed from web server1), in case of web server2 it would be `<!-- Machine Name= WEBSERVER2-->` I can find where the site is running by doing view source and searching for machine name text. However i was wondering if i could create a bookmarklet which when clicked would give me the machine name.

Does anyone know if that is even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server-side code add something like :

```
<script>
var SERVER_NAME="server1";
</script>
```

and in the browser : `javascript:alert(SERVER_NAME);`

This bookmarklet *should* work.

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.match(/Machine Name= (.*?)-->/)[1])
```

Comment: thanks. can we do it for this text. <!-- Machine Name= WEBSERVER2-->

Comment: It worked but it seems to only retrieve first dash value if the machine name is  <!-- Machine Name= WEB-SERVER-2--> (it returns WEB)

Comment: I changed the regex, check it.